# Implementing android vintage filter

Tags: android, image, graphics, filter

How to implement Vintage, LightLeak and Punch filters in android? 
I found this http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/ tutorials, but there is no such filters there.

Comment: You might consider explaining, **completely and precisely**, what "Vintage, LightLeak and Punch filters" are and where/how you wish to use them.

Comment: For other people, who will face that problem. Vintage (and other filters) is not define, I mean everyone can make his vintage filter. Library from Evgeni's post is very usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this library (including a demo of how you can process photos leveraging the ndk):

https://github.com/lightbox/PhotoProcessing

Comment: Thank you, Evgeni. That library is what I was looking for.